# Manga where the main character can see dropped item indicators

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character can see dropped item indicators as well as the monsters. It has a scene where there's golems and loot drops everywhere.

The main character in the story is the only one, and I believe he has an inventory skill. He follows or asks adventurers who are going to fight the golems. There are a large number of them and the page ends up buried in the drops such as ore and building materials.

Comment: This all sounds very generic and tropey. Can you remember anything else about this at all that you could [edit] in? When did you read this? Any plot points or story elements? Is the main character unique in this ability? Can you remember anything else about the golem scene and those surrounding it? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into the question.

Comment: Inventory skills are very common in Isekai manga and manga adaptations to anime.

Comment: if I remember correctly it stood out to me because no mater the loot if he picked herbs the loot marker was left with the same thing even when others had picked/slain

Comment: Was the main character a native of the world? Summoned there? Reincarnated? What sort of magic was in the world? What sort of monsters? Was there any sex or nudity? Was it gratuitous fanservice?

Comment: I only remember little bits of it, I think mainly sword and magic I think its an Isekai type and i think his first kill was a horned rabbit and after the kill it dropped the same and with the golems the mc was going crazy because of the large amount of loot

Comment: I have found it now on another site

Comment: i will live freely in another world with equipment manufacturing cheat

Answer (score 2):

[*I Will Live Freely in Another World With Equipment Manufacturing Cheat*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=160278)

[image: Cover of first issue of I Will Live Freely in Another World With Equipment Manufacturing Cheat]

> There’s the ordinary 29-year-old salesman named Touji Akino who, one day, is suddenly brought to another world. However, it turns out that he was a byproduct of a kingdom’s hero summoning ritual and, since the people around him have better skills and levels than he does, he is quickly kicked out of the kingdom. However, he has a unique cheat skill that allows him to look at the status of any object he is touching. Using this power, he resolves to live a slow life and attain a harem of cute girls and mascot characters.

Comment: It looks like you did indeed find it, but can you provide some details that show how it matches? That way, it will help other people looking for the same comic. Also, don't forget to accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Because it is a self-answer, you have to wait 48 hours after asking.